# Calling methods with array output twice in same scope

Tags: java

Suppose you have a method that outputs arrays of different sizes.

Before you use it, you need to create an array reference variable. Before you can do that, you need to find the array length, e.g.

```
int[] intArray = new int[methodReturnsArray().length]
```

And then you can set intArray to your array produced by methodReturnsArray().

I feel a bit uneasy about this, because we're calling methodReturnsArray() twice: once to find out how big the array is, and again to set it equal to the reference variable.

Is that wasting resources to call the method twice, or is the array only created once (when you find its size)?

Edit: I know you can just initialize intArray to the method returned by the array. But for some complicated reasons (to do with "methodReturnsArray" being called in a loop with a different-sized array for each iteration) I need to know whether calling twice will waste computational resources.

Comment: i think we need to see the content of `methodReturnsArray`.

Comment: After your edit I must say that I expect there is some design error in your application. Maybe you should explain in more detail what you try to achieve, because it sure sounds like you do are trying something very odd. Calling the method twice will definitely waste resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how you will then fill new array variable.

But the common approach will be introducing new local variable for saving reference to original array from method `methodReturnsArray`. i.e.:

```
int[] methodArray = methodReturnsArray();
int[] intArray = new int[methodArray.length];
...
```

Then the best way for copying an array is `System.arrayCopy(...)` method.
This approach will work in any case, and it will prevent you from doing things in method `methodReturnsArray` twice.

Comment: Why would you ever do it this way? It is quite possible to directly put the result of the method call into the variable without initializing it first. There is especially no need to copy the array.

Comment: @TillHelgeHelwig we don't know all goals of mentioned code's author. May be he need to make a copy of an array...

Comment: Well, okay. I'm calling methodReturnsArray for each iteration of a loop. Each one produces an array of different length. I want to add all entries to a list. I can't merely set the output equal to a variable, as I'd need a different name for each one (and you can't have variables of variables). I *can* run a for loop, calling the size directly from the method, and then adding each entry to the list directly from calling the method (without giving it a reference). Problem with this is, I need to call the method numerous times here, which seems like very bad programming practice.

Comment: Hmm...I think the System.arrayCopy method should do the trick. Thanks for the help, everyone!!